# How to use a layout from a gem in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, layout, rubygems

I am making a gem https://github.com/BDMADE/college-admin , It is a simple a layout of an admin template, I am making this gem, for why, I want to re-use in my several rails app.

My welcome controller:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
layout 'college-admin/main'

  def index
    @hello = 'Hello Word'
  end
end
```

My views:

```
<h1>Welcome#index</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/welcome/index.html.erb</p>
<%= @hello %>
```

But when I call from my welcome controller of a `demo` project, it does shows this error.

[image]

So that, My question is how to use my layout(which is laid in `college-admin` gem) in this controller ?
Should I any change in `college-admin` gem to display it's layout ?

Comment: I included this gem in my Gemfile:
` gem 'college-admin', git: 'git@github.com:BDMADE/college-admin.git'
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution:
Just use this on lib/college/admin.rb:

`require "college/admin/engine"`

before:

```
require "college/admin/version"

module College
  module Admin
    # Your code goes here...
  end
end
```

After the change:

```
require "college/admin/version"
require "college/admin/engine"

module College
  module Admin
    # Your code goes here...
  end
end
```

From the controller:
`layout 'main'`

Answer (score 0):

You need an [engine](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html) which is a gem with added integration in to the Rails stack.

> Engines can be considered miniature applications that provide
>   functionality to their host applications. A Rails application is
>   actually just a "supercharged" engine, with the Rails::Application
>   class inheriting a lot of its behavior from Rails::Engine.

You can create a new engine with:

```
bundle exec rails plugin new <NAME> --mountable --full --dummy-path=spec/dummy
```

Comment: I follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24247949/rendering-a-view-from-my-ruby-on-rails-gem
But it shows me `<module:Admin>': uninitialized constant Engine (NameError)`

Comment: I add Engine in my gem as like :
`require 'college/admin/version'

module College
  module Admin
    class Engine < Rails ::Engine
    end
  end
end
`

Comment: I linked the official Rails Engine guide in the answer :)

Comment: But it gives error while I am going to make bundle update in `demo` app.

Comment: I'd highly recommend to start a new engine with `rails plugin` and then copy any code from your existing gem to the engine.